# Sum of the elements of diagonal of matrix c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, loops, for-loop, vector

I want to find the sum of the diagonals of matrix that defined by user with this code , it works for main diagonal but not for secondary diagonal and i don't understand what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int r, c, j,i,k,sum1,sum2;
    cout << "Enter the size of matrix: ";
    cin >> j;
    int matrix[j][j];

    for (r = 0; r < j; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < j; c++) {
            cout << "matrix" << "[" << r << "]" << "[" << c << "] = ";
            cin >> matrix[r][c];
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";

    for ( i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        for ( k = 0; k < j; k++) {
            cout << " "<<matrix[i][k] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

cout<<"\n";

cout<<"Main diagonal is: ";
for( i=0;i<j;i++){
    cout<<matrix[i][i];
}
cout<<"\n";


for( i=0;i<j;i++){
    sum1=sum1+matrix[i][i];}
    cout<<"Sum of the elements of main diagonal is: "<<sum1;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n";

cout<<"Secondary diagonal is: ";
for(i=0,k=j-1;i<j;i++,k--){
    cout<<matrix[i][k];
}


for(i=0,k=j-1;i<j;i++,k--){
    sum2=sum2+matrix[i][k];
    }

    cout<<"Sum of the elements of secondary diagonal is: "<<sum2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know how to write with _if_ but I want to write like this

Comment: what is the meaning of "works not" ? compiler errors? runtime errors? wrong results?

Comment: The variables `sum1` and `sum2` are uninitialized.

Comment: **what is the meaning of "works not" ?** i meant wrong result.

Comment: @GamarMustafa -- You tagged this as `visual-studio`, but the visual studio C++ compiler never allowed code like this: `int matrix[j][j];`.  Was this one of your errors?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie opss, i think it is a habit to tag visual studio. Actually i wrote in dev c++

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I included some comments in the code.

```
#include <iostream>

/* try to avoid "using namespace ...", as it pollutes the global namespace */
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main() {
    /* I moved r and c into the block they belong to */
    int j,i,k,sum1,sum2;
    //cout << "Enter the size of matrix: ";
    //cin >> j;
    /* let's use a fixed-size array for now, otherwise you'll have to
     * dynamically allocate your array using "new" or better use std::vector */
    j = 4;
    int matrix[j][j];

    for (int r {0}; r < j; ++r) {
        for (int c {0}; c < j; ++c) {
            matrix[r][c] = r-c; /* this way, diagonals show very clearly */
            //cout << "matrix" << "[" << r << "]" << "[" << c << "] = ";
            //cin >> matrix[r][c];
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";

    for ( i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
        for ( k = 0; k < j; ++k) {
            cout << " "<< matrix[i][k] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

cout<<"\n";

cout<<"Main diagonal is: ";
for( i=0;i<j;++i){
    cout << matrix[i][i] << " ";
}
cout<<"\n";

/* initialise your sums */
sum1 = 0;
sum2 = 0;

for( i=0;i<j;i++){
    sum1=sum1+matrix[i][i];}

cout<<"Sum of the elements of main diagonal is: "<<sum1;
cout<<"\n";
cout<<"\n";

cout<<"Secondary diagonal is: ";
for(i=0,k=j-1;i<j; ++i, --k){
    cout << matrix[i][k] << " ";
}
cout<<"\n";
cout<<"\n";


for(i=0,k=j-1;i<j;i++,k--){
    sum2 = sum2+matrix[i][k];
    }

    cout<<"Sum of the elements of secondary diagonal is: "<<sum2;
    return 0;
}
```

Run it and you'll find that it works as expected. You were very close to the solution, the main problems were the lack of initialisations of your sum variables and that you need to use `new` or better yet something like `std::vector` for dynamically-sized arrays.
Also, please don't use post-increment in loops (`i++`). What you mean is pre-increment (`++i`).

Comment: Thanks a lot )) but i have one more question : What does "as it pollutes the global namespace" mean?

Comment: Part 1:
In C++, you can use namespaces to avoid naming conflicts. As a somewhat weird example, say you have automated your house and want to write functions that take care of your cat and your dog. Then you could put all the functions pertaining to your dog into ```namespace dog{ }``` and do the same for all cat-related functions. You could then in each namespace write a function ```feed()``` and call it with either ```dog::feed()``` or ```cat::feed()```, which makes your code clean and understandable.

Comment: Part 2:
 However, if you write ```using namespace dog``` and ```using namespace cat```, then you'd get a naming conflict, because suddenly, you have two functions with the name ```feed```.
And the same happens if you write ```using namespace std```. Suddenly, all functions etc. declared in the namespace ```std``` are available in the global namespace, and therefore, all those names are now unavailable, because if you'd use them, you'd cause a naming conflict.
So it's better to not drag all the declarations from ```std``` into the global namespace, to avoid conflicts. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Oh, and by writing ```using std::cout```, you only make ```cout``` available in the global namespace, but leave everything else the way it is. So it's a much less intrusive measure.

Answer (score 5):

For starters Variable Length Arrays is not a standard C++ feature. Use instead the class template `std::vector`.

For example

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix( j, std::vector<int>( j ) );
```

Or at least allocate arrays dynamically as for example

```
int **matrix = new int *[j];
for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ ) matrix[i] = new int[j];
```

In this case you should free all allocated memory before exiting the program as

```
for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ ) delete [] matrix[i];
delete [] matrix;
```

Secondly neither sum1 nor sum2 were initialized.

```
int r, c, j,i,k,sum1,sum2;
```

To calculate the sum of elements of the secondary diagonal you can write

```
sum2 = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ ){
    sum2 += matrix[i][j - i - 1];
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you post-increment the loop variables?

Comment: @RL-S It is no matter for scalar types in a loop.

Comment: If the compiler optimises it away, that's true. But I think it's always better to show your intent clearly. And that probably isn't to evaluate first, and then increment.

Comment: @RL-S This question was already asked in this forum. You can find it if you want.